# Ajax Country City Select Menu onChange() not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, onchange

I've come across an excellent tutorial for creating drop down menus that can change dynamically.

Here is the link.

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html

Here is the demo

http://roshanbh.com.np/dropdown/

---

I am fiddling with the code a bit and I am skipping the portion where you select a state.

Here is the findCity.php file

```
<!--//---------------------------------+
//  Developed by Roshan Bhattarai    |
//  http://roshanbh.com.np           |
//  Contact for custom scripts       |
//  or implementation help.          |
//  email-nepaliboy007@yahoo.com     |
//---------------------------------+-->
<?
#### Roshan's Ajax dropdown code with php
#### Copyright reserved to Roshan Bhattarai - nepaliboy007@yahoo.com
#### if you have any problem contact me at http://roshanbh.com.np
#### fell free to visit my blog http://php-ajax-guru.blogspot.com
?>

<? $country = $_GET['country'];
$link  = mysql_connect("snip","snip","snip");
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('snip');
$query="SELECT city FROM location WHERE country='$country'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="city">
<option>Select City</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value><?=$row['city']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Opening the findCity.php with a country variable works fine

http://globatum.com/admin/findCity.php?country=United%20States

I am not able to figure out why the value from the country list is not properly passing through this function

```
function getCity(country) {
        var strURL="findCity.php?country="+ country;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadycountrychange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {                        
                        document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }

    }
```

Any ideas here?

ADDED NOTES

```
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a javascript error on the page, which @nevermind beat me to point out. That's fine, but you have another problem that seems to just be a misunderstanding on your end. The line

```
req.onreadycountrychange = function() {
```

doesn't make sense, and needs to be instead:

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
```

The name of the function `onreadystatechange` is a little bit confusing in this context, but it doesn't have anything to do with 'State' as in 'State/Country'. This is referring to the current state of the `XMLHttpRequest` object. Basically that function, `onreadystatechange`, just gets called whenever the state of the request object is updated.

Read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in code, on test page:

```
if (req.readyState == 4 {
```

Should be, of course:  `if (req.readyState == 4 )`

If this doesn't fix problem, we can try something else. :)